# Is there any way to implement select all option in lumx Select?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material, lumx

I am currently using lumx Select with multiple choices in my angular material application. I have to implement a 'select all' option in the select to select all the values in the dropdown.

I referred the documentation for angular select but can't able to find whether it has native support for 'select all' option.
 Doc : [Lumx Select](http://ui.lumapps.com/components/select)

Comment: How is this related to Angular Material?

Comment: Forgot to mention that it is an angular material application. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

From the docs you referenced, the distinction between selected and not selected items is given by two attributes: `ng-model="vm.selectModel.selectedPeople"` and `lx-choices="vm.selectPeople"`.

So basically you would have to create an "All" option to include in `lx-choices` (`vm.selectPeople` in this case) and then detect when it's selected. This can be done invoking a function in your controller:

HTML:

```
<lx-select ... lx-multiple="true" change="$scope.selectCallback(newValue, oldValue)">
```

Controller

```
vm.selectCallback = selectCallback;
function selectCallback(_newValue, _oldValue) {
    console.log('Old value: ', _oldValue);
    console.log('New value: ', _newValue);
    if (_newValue == 'all')
       vm.selectModel.selectedPeople = vm.selectPeople.slice()

}
```

Notice in the function we detect the "All" option and change the model accordingly.

See my fork from someone's select example with that feature implemented:
https://jsfiddle.net/Khullah/wyfcy6ko/1/